# PC beeps once and then turns off

Tags: boot, memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

I recently got a new motherboard because I am pretty sure the current one is a bit dodgy. I built it outside of the case and powered it on, however it turns on, beeps once and then almost immediately shuts off. I know that it isn't a PSU issue, and I am pretty sure it isn't a CPU issue. One thing that is interesting is that when I unplug the CPU 4-pin connector and turn on the PC, it all runs "normally". It should be noted that I don't have the CPU cooler currently installed as it just gets in the way of doing these tests and other cables.

What could this issue be?

Comment: "I don't have the CPU cooler currently installed...."

Comment: What @Mazura said. You don't run a PC without the cooler installed. If installing the cooler doesn't fix things, you should take your computer to a qualified local PC technician for analysis.

Comment: There aren't any local computer technicians in my area which sucks, however I am wondering if there is anything else I can do that may help this situation without purchasing a new CPU.